# ui-grid, error when scrolling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am getting the following error when I scroll in `ui-grid`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'percentage' of undefined
```

Interestingly I get the same error on the `ui-grid` tutorial site so it is possible it is just simply a bug.

Here is a plunker that shows the [issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/BYV4fWGhBLgJciVccqKZ?p=preview).

Here are the grid options I am using:

```
mc.gridOptions = {
    data: mc.people,
    enableSorting: true,
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      mc.gridApi = gridApi;
    },
    columnDefs: [
      {field: 'name'},
      {field: 'age'},
      {field: 'state', enableSorting: false}
    ]
  };
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here? As far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: it seems that the file has a name `ui-grid-unstable.js`, so it is pretty likely that this is a bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would mention this in the comment box, but I need the space and the formatting to explain that you probably need to bring this up to their attention:

First you are using an unstable version, your best bet is to use a stable version that is being used and tested.

The unstable version is throwing a bug in the code below.. please review all my comments in asterisk (******) :

```
// Scroll the render container viewport when the mousewheel is used
$elm.bind('wheel mousewheel DomMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(evt) {
  // use wheelDeltaY

  var newEvent = GridUtil.normalizeWheelEvent(evt);

  var args = { target: $elm };

  *****THIS STATEMENT IS TRUE BECAUSE YOU SCROLLED VERTICALLY, ARGS.Y IS SET*****
  if (newEvent.deltaY !== 0) {
    var scrollYAmount = newEvent.deltaY * -120;

    // Get the scroll percentage
    var scrollYPercentage = (containerCtrl.viewport[0].scrollTop + scrollYAmount) / rowContainer.getVerticalScrollLength();

    // Keep scrollPercentage within the range 0-1.
    if (scrollYPercentage < 0) { scrollYPercentage = 0; }
    else if (scrollYPercentage > 1) { scrollYPercentage = 1; }

    ***THIS IS SET***
    args.y = { percentage: scrollYPercentage, pixels: scrollYAmount };
  }

  *****THIS STATEMENT IS FALSE BECAUSE YOU NEVER SCROLLED HORIZONTALLY, ARGS.X IS NOT SET*****
  if (newEvent.deltaX !== 0) {
    var scrollXAmount = newEvent.deltaX * -120;

    // Get the scroll percentage
    var scrollLeft = GridUtil.normalizeScrollLeft(containerCtrl.viewport);
    var scrollXPercentage = (scrollLeft + scrollXAmount) / (colContainer.getCanvasWidth() - colContainer.getViewportWidth());

    // Keep scrollPercentage within the range 0-1.
    if (scrollXPercentage < 0) { scrollXPercentage = 0; }
    else if (scrollXPercentage > 1) { scrollXPercentage = 1; }

    ***THIS DOESNT GET SET SINCE IT WILL NOT REACH THIS POINT***
    args.x = { percentage: scrollXPercentage, pixels: scrollXAmount };
  }

  *****THROWS AN ERROR BECAUSE ARGS.X IS NULL & DOESNT EXIST*****
  // Let the parent container scroll if the grid is already at the top/bottom
  if ((args.y.percentage !== 0 && args.y.percentage !== 1) || (args.x.percentage !== 0 && args.x.percentage !== 1)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }

  uiGridCtrl.fireScrollingEvent(args);
});
```